# UnreachableBrowserException and SessionNotCreatedException on iOS Appium Automation

Tags: java, ios, automation, appium

Team,

Description: Getting the error UnreachableBrowserException and SessionNotCreatedException when trying to Launch the App on iOS actual device using Appium Server.

**I am using latest xCode ver8.0-beta,is it causing this issue? does the appium not support with latest xcode**
UIAutomation option is also enabled

Did go through few of the blogs and comments such as,non of them worked:
  1. Updating the chormedriver
  2. changing the browser name in capabilities
  3. Including the jar files

**Below is the code which i am trying to launch the App:**

```
package mytest;
import java.io.File;

import java.net.URL;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;

 import org.testng.annotations.Test;

 import io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver;

import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;



public class testone {


public static IOSDriver<MobileElement> driver;


@BeforeClass

public static void setupBeforeClass() throws Exception{


File appDir = new File ("//Users//gangaiahl//Downloads//AppFile-Developer");

File app = new File (appDir,"Cars.app");


DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

//capabilities.setCapability("noReset", true);

capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");

capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Carsguide's iPhone");

capabilities.setCapability("udid", "788760e7244680fab61b93da145b67df8cb5a");

capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, " ");

capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "9.3.2");

capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM, "MAC");


capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());

//capabilities.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", true);

//capabilities.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", true);



driver = new IOSDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

 }



@Test

public void test()

{

 System.out.println("Hello");


}



}
```

Below is the Appium logs:

```
  [HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session {"capabilities":{"desiredCapabilities":  {"app":"/Users/gangaiahl/Downloads/AppFile-   Developer/CarsGuide.app","platformVersion":"9.3.2","browserName":"  ","platformName":"iOS","udid":"788760e7244680fab61b93d48da145b67df8cb5a","device Name":"Carsguide's  iPhone","platform":"MAC"},"requiredCapabilities":null},"desiredCapabilities": {"app":"/Users/gangaiahl/Downloads/AppFile- Developer/CarsGuide.app","platformVersion":"9.3.2","browserName":"  ","platformName":"iOS","udid":"788760e7244680fab61b93d48da145b67df8cb5a","device Name":"Carsguide's iPhone","platform":"MAC"},"requiredCapabilities":null}



     [debug] [MJSONWP] Bad parameters: BadParametersError: Parameters were  incorrect. We wanted {"required":["desiredCapabilities"],"optional": ["requiredCapabilities","sessionId","id","sessionId","id","sessionId","id","sessionId","id","sessionId","id","sessionId","id","sessionId","id","sessionId","id", "sessionId","id","sessionId","id","sessionId","id","sessionId","id","sessionId", "id","sessionId","id","sessionId","id","sessionId","id","sessionId","id","sessio nId","id","sessionId","id","sessionId","id","sessionId","id","sessionId","id","s essionId","id","sessionId","id","sessionId","id"]} and you sent  ["capabilities","desiredCapabilities","requiredCapabilities"]

     [HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 400 1 ms - 609 



     [HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session {"capabilities":{"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"/Users/gangaiahl/Downloads/AppFile-Developer/CarsGuide.app","platformVersion":"9.3.2","browserName":" ","platformName":"iOS","udid":"788760e7244680fab61b93d48da145b67df8cb5a","deviceName":"Carsguide's iPhone","platform":"MAC"},"requiredCapabilities":null}}



      [debug] [MJSONWP] Bad parameters: BadParametersError: Parameters were  incorrect. We wanted {"required":["desiredCapabilities"],"optional": ["requiredCapabilities","sessionId","id","sessionId","id","sessionId","id","sessionId","id","sessionId","id","sessionId","id","sessionId","id","sessionId","id", "sessionId","id","sessionId","id","sessionId","id","sessionId","id","sessionId","id","sessionId","id","sessionId","id","sessionId","id","sessionId","id","sessionId","id","sessionId","id","sessionId","id","sessionId","id","sessionId","id","s essionId","id","sessionId","id","sessionId","id","sessionId","id"]} and you sent  ["capabilities"]



          [HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 400 1 ms - 581 



       [HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities": {"app":"/Users/gangaiahl/Downloads/AppFile- Developer/CarsGuide.app","platformVersion":"9.3.2","browserName":" ","platformName":"iOS","udid":"788760e7244680fab61b93d48da145b67df8cb5a","deviceName":"Carsguide's iPhone","platform":"MAC"},"requiredCapabilities":null}



       [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args:   [{"app":"/Users/gangaiahl/D...

       [Appium] Creating new IosDriver session

      [Appium] Capabilities:

      [Appium]   app: '/Users/gangaiahl/Downloads/AppFile-Developer/CarsGuide.app'

     [Appium]   platformVersion: '9.3.2'

    [Appium]   browserName: ' '

    [Appium]   platformName: 'iOS'

    [Appium]   udid: '788760e7244680fab61b93d48da145b67df8cb5a'

    [Appium]   deviceName: 'Carsguide\'s iPhone'

    [Appium]   platform: 'MAC'

    [Appium]   noReset: true

    [Appium]   nativeInstrumentsLib: true

    [Appium]   showIOSLog: true

    [BaseDriver] The following capabilities were provided, but are not  recognized by appium: platform.

    [BaseDriver] Session created with session id: 4e92ff24-ebe6-4567-923b-3e439ce09a06

    [debug] [iOS] Not auto-detecting udid.

    [BaseDriver] Using local app '/Users/gangaiahl/Downloads/AppFile-Developer/CarsGuide.app'

    [debug] [iOS] Removing any remaining instruments sockets



    [debug] [iOS] Cleaned up instruments socket  /var/folders/05/79kfthm94qjd3bngd2l5pv7r0mx69v/T/instruments_sock

    [debug] [iOS] No language specified. Using default strings

    [debug] [iOS] Strings file not found. Looking in 'en.lproj' directory

     [iOS] Could not file localizable strings file 'Localizable.strings'!

     [debug] [ios-app-utils] Getting bundle ID from app

     [iOS] Extracted bundleID: au.com.onewaytraffic.carsguide from app:  /Users/gangaiahl/Downloads/AppFile-Developer/CarsGuide.app

         [debug] [iOS] Creating instruments



    [debug] [UIAuto] Preparing bootstrap code

     [debug] [UIAuto] Dynamic bootstrap dir:  /Users/gangaiahl/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap

   [debug] [UIAuto] Dynamic env:  {"nodePath":"/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node","commandProxyClientPath":"/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-ios-driver/node_modules/appium-uiauto/build/lib/bin/command-proxy-client.js","instrumentsSock":"/var/folders/05/79kfthm94qjd3bngd2l5pv7r0mx69v/T/instruments_sock","interKeyDelay":null,"justLoopInfinitely":false,"autoAcceptAlerts":false,"autoDismissAlerts":false,"sendKeyStrategy":"grouped"}



      [debug] [UIAuto] Dynamic bootstrap code: // This file is automatically generated. Do not manually modify!

          ...



         [debug] [UIAuto] Dynamic bootstrap path: /Users/gangaiahl/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-c05643b7d8d19d44.js

            [debug] [UIAuto] Reusing dynamic bootstrap: /Users/gangaiahl/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-c05643b7d8d19d44.js

       [debug] [iOS] Reset not set, continuing

       [debug] [iOSLog] Attempting iOS device log capture via libimobiledevice idevicesyslog

      [debug] [iOSLog] Found idevicesyslog: '/usr/local/bin/idevicesyslog'



        [debug] [iOS] Creating iDevice object with udid 788760e7244680fab61b93d48da145b67df8cb5a



       [debug] [iOS] App is not installed. Will try to install.



             [MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error:  Installing /Users/gangaiahl/Downloads/AppFile-Developer/CarsGuide.app failed

        at    /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-ios-driver/node_modules/node-idevice/main.js:159:6

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:193:7)

    at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)

     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)

    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:850:16)

    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:5)



   [HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 1349 ms - 213
```

Below is the Eclipse Console logs:

```
   [TestNG] Running:

    /private/var/folders/05/79kfthm94qjd3bngd2l5pv7r0mx69v/T/testng-eclipse-   -2055605734/testng-customsuite.xml



     Sep 12, 2016 3:00:36 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession

            INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end

      log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger  (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).

      log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

      Sep 12, 2016 3:00:36 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake  createSession

    INFO: Falling back to straight W3C remote end connection

     Sep 12, 2016 3:00:36 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession

    INFO: Falling back to original OSS JSON Wire Protocol.

    [Utils] Attempting to create /Users/gangaiahl/Documents/workspace/mytest/test-output/Default suite/Default test.xml

   [Utils]   Directory /Users/gangaiahl/Documents/workspace/mytest/test-output/Default suite exists: true

   FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass setupBeforeClass

   org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.

   Build info: version: '3.0.0-beta3', revision: 'c7b525d', time: '2016-09-01 14:57:03 -0700'

   System info: host: 'NCA1005547', ip: '10.65.212.71', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.6', java.version: '1.8.0_66'

     Driver info: driver.version: IOSDriver

    at   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:618)

     at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:40)

     at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)

      at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.execute(IOSDriver.java:1)

       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:242)

           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:129)

         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)

           at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:36)

              at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:114)

       at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:132)

           at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.<init>(IOSDriver.java:82)

        at mytest.testone.setupBeforeClass(testone.java:37)

      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

          at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)

             at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:100)

           at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:515)

        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:216)

            at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:143)

        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:169)

      at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)

      at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:746)

      at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:600)

     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)

           at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)

     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)

     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)

      at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)

     at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)

    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1264)

    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1189)

    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1104)

   at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1076)

    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:126)

  at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:152)

  at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:57)

  Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to  create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{app=/Users/gangaiahl/Downloads/AppFile-Developer/CarsGuide.app, platformVersion=9.3.2, browserName= , platformName=iOS, udid=788760e7244680fab61b93d48da145b67df8cb5a, deviceName=Carsguide's iPhone,  platform=MAC}], required capabilities = null

    Build info: version: '3.0.0-beta3', revision: 'c7b525d', time: '2016-09-01 14:57:03 -0700'

  System info: host: 'NCA1005547', ip: '10.65.212.71', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.6', java.version: '1.8.0_66'

   Driver info: driver.version: IOSDriver

   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:80)

   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)

    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:69)

   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:597)

    ... 36 more



    SKIPPED: test



     ===============================================

     Default test

     Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1

    Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0

     ===============================================





     ===============================================

    Default suite

    Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1

    Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0

     ===============================================



   [TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@5419f379: 9 ms

   [TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@36d4b5c: 18 ms

    [Utils] Attempting to create    /Users/gangaiahl/Documents/workspace/mytest/test-output/junitreports/TEST- mytest.testone.xml

     [Utils]   Directory /Users/gangaiahl/Documents/workspace/mytest/test-output/junitreports exists: true

  [TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@20e2cbe0: 3 ms

     [TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@7c16905e: 5 ms

       [Utils] Attempting to create /Users/gangaiahl/Documents/workspace/mytest/test-output/old/Default suite/toc.html

       [Utils]   Directory /Users/gangaiahl/Documents/workspace/mytest/test-output/old/Default suite exists: true

        [Utils] Attempting to create /Users/gangaiahl/Documents/workspace/mytest/test-output/old/Default suite/Default test.properties

      [Utils]   Directory /Users/gangaiahl/Documents/workspace/mytest/test-output/old/Default suite exists: true

        [Utils] Attempting to create /Users/gangaiahl/Documents/workspace/mytest/test-output/old/Default suite/index.html

        [Utils]   Directory /Users/gangaiahl/Documents/workspace/mytest/test-output/old/Default suite exists: true

     [Utils] Attempting to create /Users/gangaiahl/Documents/workspace/mytest/test-output/old/Default suite/main.html

      [Utils]   Directory /Users/gangaiahl/Documents/workspace/mytest/test-output/old/Default suite exists: true

       [Utils] Attempting to create /Users/gangaiahl/Documents/workspace/mytest/test-output/old/Default suite/groups.html

       [Utils]   Directory /Users/gangaiahl/Documents/workspace/mytest/test-output/old/Default suite exists: true

          [Utils] Attempting to create /Users/gangaiahl/Documents/workspace/mytest/test-output/old/Default suite/classes.html

         [Utils]   Directory /Users/gangaiahl/Documents/workspace/mytest/test-output/old/Default suite exists: true

        [Utils] Attempting to create /Users/gangaiahl/Documents/workspace/mytest/test-output/old/Default suite/reporter-output.html

        [Utils]   Directory /Users/gangaiahl/Documents/workspace/mytest/test-output/old/Default suite exists: true

         [Utils] Attempting to create /Users/gangaiahl/Documents/workspace/mytest/test-output/old/Default suite/methods-not-run.html

          [Utils]   Directory /Users/gangaiahl/Documents/workspace/mytest/test-output/old/Default suite exists: true

        [Utils] Attempting to create /Users/gangaiahl/Documents/workspace/mytest/test-output/old/Default suite/testng.xml.html

           [Utils]   Directory /Users/gangaiahl/Documents/workspace/mytest/test-output/old/Default suite exists: true

       [Utils] Attempting to create /Users/gangaiahl/Documents/workspace/mytest/test-output/old/index.html

         [Utils]   Directory /Users/gangaiahl/Documents/workspace/mytest/test-output/old exists: true

         [TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@100fc185: 8 ms

        [Utils] Attempting to create /Users/gangaiahl/Documents/workspace/mytest/test-output/testng-failed.xml

        [Utils]   Directory /Users/gangaiahl/Documents/workspace/mytest/test-output exists: true

         [Utils] Attempting to create /Users/gangaiahl/Documents/workspace/mytest/test-output/Default suite/testng-failed.xml

        [Utils]   Directory /Users/gangaiahl/Documents/workspace/mytest/test-output/Default suite exists: true

         [TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]:   3 ms
```

**More Information:**
        When even try to launch the App from Appium inspector its not working,      below error always throws back:

```
   HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/status {}



          [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.getStatus() with args: []



         [MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.getStatus() result:   {"build":{"version":"1.5.3"...



     [HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 9 ms - 83 



       [HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/sessions {}



     [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.getSessions() with args: []



     [MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.getSessions() result: []

     [HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/sessions 200 2 ms - 40 

    [HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"platformName":"iOS","platformVersion":"9.3.2","app":"/Users/gangaiahl/Downloads/CarsGuide.app","automationName":"Appium","udid":"788760e7244680fab61b93d48da145b67df8cb5a","deviceName":"CarsGuideDev\rCarsguideiPhone"}}

    [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args:            [{"platformName":"iOS","pla...

    [Appium] Creating new IosDriver session

  [Appium] Capabilities:

   [Appium]   platformName: 'iOS'

    [Appium]   platformVersion: '9.3.2'

      [Appium]   app: '/Users/gangaiahl/Downloads/CarsGuide.app'

     [Appium]   automationName: 'Appium'

      [Appium]   udid: '788760e7244680fab61b93d48da145b67df8cb5a'

     [Appium]   deviceName: 'CarsGuideDev\rCarsguideiPhone'

     [Appium]   noReset: true

        [Appium]   nativeInstrumentsLib: true

     [Appium]   showIOSLog: true



    [BaseDriver] Session created with session id: 7ad334c3-9a95-44bd-a718-d9e41d79dcd4

   [debug] [iOS] Not auto-detecting udid.



   [BaseDriver] Using local app '/Users/gangaiahl/Downloads/CarsGuide.app'

   [debug] [iOS] Removing any remaining instruments sockets

    [debug] [iOS] Cleaned up instruments socket /var/folders/05/79kfthm94qjd3bngd2l5pv7r0mx69v/T/instruments_sock

 [debug] [iOS] No language specified. Using default strings

[debug] [iOS] Strings file not found. Looking in 'en.lproj' directory

[iOS] Could not file localizable strings file 'Localizable.strings'!

         [debug] [ios-app-utils] Getting bundle ID from app

              [iOS] Extracted bundleID: au.com.oewytrfc.cars from app: /Users/gangaiahl/Downloads/CarsGuide.app

          [debug] [iOS] Creating instruments

           [debug] [UIAuto] Preparing bootstrap code

           [debug] [UIAuto] Dynamic bootstrap dir: /Users/gangaiahl/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap

        [debug] [UIAuto] Dynamic env: {"nodePath":"/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node","commandProxyClientPath":"/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-ios-driver/node_modules/appium-uiauto/build/lib/bin/command-proxy-client.js","instrumentsSock":"/var/folders/05/79kfthm94qjd3bngd2l5pv7r0mx69v/T/instruments_sock","interKeyDelay":null,"justLoopInfinitely":false,"autoAcceptAlerts":false,"autoDismissAlerts":false,"sendKeyStrategy":"grouped"}



           [debug] [UIAuto] Dynamic bootstrap code: // This file is automatically generated. Do not manually modify!

     ...



  [debug] [UIAuto] Dynamic bootstrap path: /Users/gangaiahl/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-c05643b7d8d19d44.js

   [debug] [UIAuto] Reusing dynamic bootstrap: /Users/gangaiahl/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-c05643b7d8d19d44.js

   [debug] [iOS] Reset not set, continuing

    [debug] [iOSLog] Attempting iOS device log capture via libimobiledevice idevicesyslog

   [debug] [iOSLog] Found idevicesyslog: '/usr/local/bin/idevicesyslog'



     [debug] [iOS] Creating iDevice object with udid 788760e7244680fab61b93d48da145b67df8cb5a



  [debug] [iOS] App is not installed. Will try to install.



  [MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Installing /Users/gangaiahl/Downloads/CarsGuide.app failed

       at   /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/app ium-ios-driver/node_modules/node-idevice/main.js:159:6

  at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:193:7)

   at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)

   at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)

    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:850:16)

   at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:323:11)

   at emitOne (events.js:90:13)

   at Socket.emit (events.js:182:7)

   at Pipe._onclose (net.js:475:12)



  [HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 1374 ms - 195
```

Comment: Guys, I was using .app file both in my script and appium settings this was causing the issue. When i changed that to .ipa file in both of them it started working.

Comment: But still wondering that why .app file is not working , c' i used .app file earlier and it used to work absolutely fine...can some one explain me here will be helpful in future